# Applet v/s Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, applet

Whats the difference between Applet and Servlet in JAVA

Comment: It's a good idea to encourage yourself and us to put *bit* more effort in asking the question. Just googling your oneliner "Whats the difference between Applet and Servlet in JAVA" namely already gives the answers. You could for example elaborate more about the actual problem you have with the answers you found. For example how they are insufficient and so on; this way we can give a more suited answers.

Comment: After googling "Whats the difference between Applet and Servlet in JAVA", this nicely compact and to-the-point stackoverflow question came up.  Contrary to BalusC, I think the question is perfect.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Applet runs on the client, servlet runs on the server. It's as simple as that.

More specifically, that applet is downloaded to the client, and executes in a JRE inside the browser, and can display whatever it wants to display within the applet frame. The servlet instead runs on the server and (generally) produces a HTML page which is displayed in your browser.

Answer (score 5):

A Java Applet is a Java class which is run on the client's JVM (via a Browser Plugin).

A Java Servlet is run on the server-side in a Servlet container, like Apache Tomcat and the client recieves the results in the form of plain old HTML.

The key difference is that where as one runs on the client side, the other on the Server side.

Answer (score 1):

applet is the Desktop application and the Servlet is the web Application

Applet is run on the Clients machine and the Servlet is run the Server Machine And produce 
the html page on the client browser with the help of the Request And Response Parameter in 
the Java.servlet.*;
Package